# How can I add a new column to the middle of a kdb table?

Tags: kdb

I have a table in kdb/Q that looks like this:

```
table_a:([] Symbol:`X`Y`Z; StartDate:2023.09.01 2023.09.02 2023.09.03;Name:`Maria`Sam`Sydney);
```

It gives me a table that looks like this:

| Symbol | StartDate | Name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| X | 2023.09.01 | Maria |
| Y | 2023.09.02 | Sam |
| Z | 2023.09.03 | Sydney |

What I would like is to create a new column in between the StartDate and Name columns, so somethig that looks like this:

| Symbol | StartDate | EndDate | Name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| X | 2023.09.01 | 2023.09.01 | Maria |
| Y | 2023.09.02 | 2023.09.08 | Sam |
| Z | 2023.09.03 | 2023.09.14 | Sydney |

I looked up documentation, but it looks like there's only options to append rows to the ends of tables. Is there a way for me to add a new column in between using Q, or do I have to reconstruct the current table?

Comment: Sorry, it looks like the tables aren't formatting properly, but I would like for table_a to become table_b:
` table_a: ([] Symbol:`X`Y`Z; StartDate:2023.09.01 2023.09.02 2023.09.03; EndDate:2023.09.01 2023.09.08; 2023.09.14; Name:'Maria' 'Sam' 'Sydney'); `

Answer (score 5):

Updates will put new columns on the far right.

You can use [xcols](https://code.kx.com/q/ref/cols/#xcols) to move columns to the left.

```
q)table_a:update EndDate:StartDate+1 from table_a
q)`Symbol`StartDate`EndDate xcols table_a
Symbol StartDate  EndDate    Name
-----------------------------------
X      2023.09.01 2023.09.02 Maria
Y      2023.09.02 2023.09.03 Sam
Z      2023.09.03 2023.09.04 Sydney
```

A quick function could be written:

```
q)moveToRightOf:{c:`,cols[x] except z;((((1+c?y)#c),z) except `) xcols x}

//Move EnDate to right of StartDate
q)moveToRightOf[table_a;`StartDate;`EndDate]
Symbol StartDate  EndDate    Name
-----------------------------------
X      2023.09.01 2023.09.02 Maria
Y      2023.09.02 2023.09.03 Sam
Z      2023.09.03 2023.09.04 Sydney

//Use ` to move to beginning
q)moveToRightOf[table_a;`;`EndDate]
EndDate    Symbol StartDate  Name
-----------------------------------
2023.09.02 X      2023.09.01 Maria
2023.09.03 Y      2023.09.02 Sam
2023.09.04 Z      2023.09.03 Sydney
```

`moveToLeftOf` is very similar but uses ` to move to the end

```
q)moveToLeftOf:{c:cols[x] except z;(((c?y)#c),z) xcols x}

q)moveToLeftOf[table_a;`Name;`EndDate]
Symbol StartDate  EndDate    Name
-----------------------------------
X      2023.09.01 2023.09.02 Maria
Y      2023.09.02 2023.09.03 Sam
Z      2023.09.03 2023.09.04 Sydney

q)moveToLeftOf[table_a;`Symbol;`EndDate]
EndDate    Symbol StartDate  Name
-----------------------------------
2023.09.02 X      2023.09.01 Maria
2023.09.03 Y      2023.09.02 Sam
2023.09.04 Z      2023.09.03 Sydney

q)moveToLeftOf[table_a;`;`EndDate]
Symbol StartDate  Name   EndDate
-----------------------------------
X      2023.09.01 Maria  2023.09.02
Y      2023.09.02 Sam    2023.09.03
Z      2023.09.03 Sydney 2023.09.04
```

Answer (score 4):

If you have a small number of columns (that can reasonably be typed out) then you can always re-arrange columns - and create new ones - using a `select` statement rather than an `update`

```
q)select Symbol,StartDate,EndDate:StartDate+1,Name from table_a
Symbol StartDate  EndDate    Name
-----------------------------------
X      2023.09.01 2023.09.02 Maria
Y      2023.09.02 2023.09.03 Sam
Z      2023.09.03 2023.09.04 Sydney
```

(this assumes you're doing an unfiltered update, e.g. no where clause)

If you need it more generalised you would use an `xcols`-based solution as rianoc showed